# Bison code error :scanner.y:1.1-7.2: syntax error, unexpected {...}

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a lexer and a parser with flex and bison. I don't understand why my bison code won't compile. Here is my code:

scanner.y:

```
{%
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
%}

%token INT REAL BOOL STRING ID BASIC KEYWORD OP ASSIGN EQUAL NEQUAL RELATION SPECIAL

%type <boolean> BOOL
%type <num> NUM
%type <flnum> REAL
%type <name> STRING
%type <name> ID
%type <name> BASIC
%type <name> KEYWORD
%type <name> OP
%type <name> RELATION
%type <symbol> SPECIAL

%union{
    bool boolean;
      char name[20];
    char symbol;
    int num;
    float flnum;
}

%%

prog:
    block
;

block:
    '{' decls stmts '}'
;

decls:
     decls decl
     |
;

decl:
    type ID ';'
;

type:
    type '[' NUM ']'
    | BASIC
;

stmts:
    stmts stmt
    |
;

stmt:
    loc ASSIGN ‌‌BOOL ';'
    | "if" '(' ‌BOOL ')' stmt
    | "if" '(' ‌BOOL ')' stmt "else" stmt
    | "while" '(' BOOL ')' stmt
    | "do" stmt "while" '(' BOOL ')' ';'
    | "break" ';'
    | block
;

loc:
    loc '[' BOOL ']'
    | ID
;

bool:
    bool "||" join
    | join
;

join:
    join "&&" equality
    | equality
;

equality:
    equality EQUAL rel
    | equality NEQUAL rel
    | rel
;

rel:
    expr '<' expr
    | expr "<=" expr
    | expr ">=" expr
    | expr '>' expr
    |expr
;

expr:
    expr '+' term
    | expr '-' term
    | term
;

term:
    term '*' unary
    | term '/' unary
    | unary
;

unary:
    '!' unary
    | '-' unary
    | factor
;

factor:
    '(' bool ')'
    | loc
    | NUM
    | REAL
    | BOOL
;


%%

#include "lex.yy.c"

yyerror() {printf("input error!");}

int main()
{

  #ifdef YYDEBUG
  yydebug = 1;
  #endif

  yyparse();
  return 0;
}
```

scanner.l

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include "y.tab.h"
%}
sign -?
alph [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]
bool "true"|"false"

%option noyywrap

%%

"if" {sscanf(yytext, "%s", yylval.name); return(KEYWORD);}
"while" {sscanf(yytext, "%s", yylval.name); return(KEYWORD);}
"do" {sscanf(yytext, "%s", yylval.name); return(KEYWORD);}
"break" {sscanf(yytext, "%s", yylval.name); return(KEYWORD);}

"int" {sscanf(yytext,"%s", yyval.name); return(BASIC);}
"float" {sscanf(yytext,"%s", yyval.name); return(BASIC);}
"bool" {sscanf(yytext,"%s", yyval.name); return(BASIC);}

{bool} {if(strcmp(yytext, "true") == 0){yylval.boolean = true;}else if(strcmp(yytext, "false") == 0){yylval.boolean = false;} return(BOOL);}

{alph}(_|{digit}|{alph})* {sscanf(yytext, "%s", yylval.name); return(ID);}

{digit}+ {yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return(NUM);}
{sign}{digit}+.{digit}+ {yylval.flnum = atof(yytext); return(REAL);}

[\t] {}
" " {}
[\n] {}

"+" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(OP);}
"-" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(OP);}
"*" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(OP);}
"/" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(OP);}

"==" {return(EQUAL);}
"!=" {return(NEQUAL);}
"=" {return(ASSIGN);}

")" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
"{" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
"}" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
"(" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
"]" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
"[" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}
";" {yylval.symbol = yytext[0]; return(SPECIAL);}

(\'){alph}(\') {printf("<const, %s>", yytext);}
(\"){alph}{alph}+(\") {printf("<const, %s>", yytext);}
. {printf("error%s", yytext);}
%%
```

and first I run `flex scanner.l` which creates lex.yy.c as expected and then I run `bison -dy scanner.y` which causes the error:

```
scanner.y:1.1-7.2: syntax error, unexpected {...}
```

which I don't understand. I have tried `--debug` and `-t` but I get the same result.

Comment: You have `{%` but you need `%{` on the first line of `scanner.y`.

Comment: thank you for your response but that is my typo and i changed it it still gives me the same error

Comment: This is a simple typo.  I recommend you delete the question.  Also, in future, make sure the triple-backquote line does not contain the start of the code.

Comment: Try again.  And don't make typos in transcribing code into a question.  Use copy'n'paste to make sure you don't make typos.

Comment: When I change the `{%` to `5{` and  replace some U+200C (zero width non-joiner) characters in what I copy from the question, I get only the error: `bison83.y:48.14-16: symbol NUM is used, but is not defined as a token and has no rules.` (from source file `scanner.y` renamed as `bison83.y`).  This is a wholly separate problem, readily solvable.

Comment: if possible, can you explain more how did you manage to compile the .y file i don't understand what you mean by "replace some U+200C (zero width non-joiner) characters" and what does 5{ do and you are right thats a problem that this file has but after changing INT to NUM it still doesn't work

Comment: The `5{` is a typo in my comment.  When I copied the code from the question, the copy managed to include some bogus characters — I doubt they're in your source, so they're an artefact of the 'copy to web' ('copy to SO') process.  Don't worry about that.  (I did repeat the copy process; it copied the U+200C characters again, but as I said, I doubt they are in your source.)

Comment: When I change two occurrences of `NUM` to `INT`, the grammar then comes up with `26 rules never reduced` and 
`bison83.y: warning: 8 useless nonterminals and 26 useless rules`.  That's a problem in your grammar, wholly unrelated to the headline problem in the question.  You need to go back to editing the grammar so it does what you need

Comment: I finnaly managed to compile my code but i get this instead which says invalid characters which i haven't used at all
```scanner.y:58.16: invalid character: `\342'
scanner.y:58.17: invalid character: `\200'
scanner.y:58.18: invalid character: `\214'
scanner.y:58.19: invalid character: `\342'
scanner.y:58.20: invalid character: `\200'
scanner.y:58.21: invalid character: `\214'
scanner.y:59.16: invalid character: `\342'
scanner.y:59.17: invalid character: `\200'
scanner.y:59.18: invalid character: `\214'
scanner.y:60.16: invalid character: `\342'
```

Comment: If it compiles for you, great.  It probably means there's a stupid mistake somewhere in the edited file I've created.  Recopying your file, I see you mapped `INT` to `NUM` rather than `NUM` to `INT`; that's fine.  When I changed `%token INT …` to `%token NUM …`, I get the warnings about useless terminals and rules — there's also a shift/reduce conflict, I see.  That's likely causing a lot of the trouble.  It's the classic `if` vs `if ... else ...` conflict.

Comment: dude thanks alot serously i know i shouldn't comment thanks here but i really appreciate the time you're putting in

Comment: The octal escapes form the triple `\342\200\214` which is the UTF-8 encoding for U+200C Zero Width Non-Joiner.  Those need to be removed.  As I said, they're an artefact of the 'copy to SO' process (or copy from SO process).